# Can I add insulation on the outside of a bedroom wall adjacent to garage attic?

Tags: insulation, garage, attic, bedroom, spray-foam

I have a new construction home, and one of the bedrooms is adjacent to the attic above the garage. The room is always a couple degrees cooler than the other rooms, so was wondering if I could spray foam insulate the other side of the room. As you can see from the image from inside the attic, the builder insulated along the footing of the room, but not the header or the wall. Would it be bad to cover that vapor barrier?[image: Bedroom wall from attic]

Comment: If it's new construction I'd report the defect to the builder and have them handle it.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes, you can**, and yes, your **builder should have done**, and should do now for free, having failed to do it when they should have during construction.